# Could not open the editor. Android XML Editor cannot process this input

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, helios

I got this error whenever I tired to view previous version of XML file via `SVN Team => Show History`. How can I able to solve this problem?

```
Could not open the editor. Andriod XML Editor cannot process this input.
```

Answer (score 11):

You can solve the problem by changing your Eclipse preferences: Window menu -> Preferences ->  General -> Editors -> File Associations; select *.xml, choose XML Editor and click "Default" button.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem, following steps worked for me -
Open Window > Preferences > General > Content Types
Select "Text"
Under "File associations"
Select *.xml
Click remove button on right side and then ok in bottom